# Zipcode based search

Tags: php, sql, zipcode

I want to make a geographical search using US city and state or zip-code and corresponding results will be viewed. In the search we have to mention the radius distance. For example:
I would like to search between 25 miles around California.

What should I do to do this? Is there any database containing US city, state, zip, latitude, longitude information?

Answer (score 5):

[GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/)

> The GeoNames geographical database
>   covers all countries and contains over
>   eight million placenames that are
>   available for download free of charge.

There is also a webservice.

Answer (score 2):

Once you convert your zip code data to longitude and latitude, here are a couple resources for working with the coordinates.

[Converting miles to degrees longitude and latitude](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/04/27/converting-miles-to-degrees-longitude-or-latitude/)

[Computing distance from longitude and latitude](http://www.johndcook.com/lat_long_details.html)

Answer (score 1):

For zipcode-based geolocation, see http://code.google.com/p/zip-code/ for example.

Answer (score 1):

Arrr! Why do people charge for these things? Not even USPS will give you the current zipcode database for free, and the databases at the above links have not been updated for years, which can throw users for a loop. This is free public data folks!

So, I have created a database by taking an older zip dataset and wired it up to Google's Geocoding API to keep it up to date. This one has all of them through July 2011.

Download [the free zipcode dataset](http://www.lustforge.com/2011/07/20/really-free-zipcode-database-download/) as MySql, CSV, or Excel.